# Is it a good practice to carry DB values in session variable or in a cookie?

Tags: php

Is it a good practice to carry DB values in session variable or in a cookie?

Comment: What do you mean by "value" ? Connexion infos ?

Comment: no !! I mean the values Likewise user profile values etc...

Comment: for sessionvariables (like the id or name of the logged in user) it's appropriate to use $_SESSION.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a usual practice to save some values as session variables (like the user ID), not in cookie as a cookie can be changed by the user.
Just remember to regenerate the session ID when your user's rights changes (login, logout, goes on admin page etc.) to avoid session hijacking problems.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what these values are and/or the quantity of data.

For example, You wouldn't store a password or a huge BLOB of data in a cookie.

Sticking with a session id in the cookie is usually the best practice.